# Deterministic automaton whose input length is divisible by 3 or 5?

Tags: math, state, state-machine, deterministic, automaton

I only have one letter available as a language (e.g.: x). If I now enter "xxx" or "xxxxx" then the machine should accept this input because in the former case the length is 3 and in the second the length of the input is 5. And since the length should be divisible by 3 or 5, this should be accepted.

However, after hours of thinking, I can't find the solution. Can someone help me please?

I have tried the following:
q0, q1, q2, q3, q4 and q5 --> each for the rest.

q3 and q5 would be my final states, since the remainder is 0 (divisible)

Then I can enter the following transitions:

```
 q0 --> q1
 q1 --> q2
 q2 --> q3
 q3 --> q4
 q4 --> q5
 q5 --> q6
```

For example, if I have 6 "x" i.e. "xxxxxx" then I end up in state q0. So it has to be an accepting one too.

If I have 10 "x", i.e. "xxxxxxxxxx" I end up on q4.
With 11 "x" I end up at q5, which is an accepting state which is not possible.

No matter how I spin it, I keep running into problems like this. Why am I thinking so wrongly here :-S

Comment: You know how to make an automaton that accepts strings of length multiple of 3, and you know how to make an automaton that accepts strings of length multiple of 5. Now you're looking for an automaton that accepts strings of length multiple of 3 and strings of length multiple of 5. This is the automaton for the ***union*** of two languages for which you have an automaton. This can be achieved by a kind of "cross-product" of automatons.

Comment: TL;DR: try with 15 states

Comment: You are right! I tried it out and it worked! Thank you very much, I was never thinking about it to have 15 states! But it seems now logical to me. Do you also know the mathemtical reason for this? Does this have something to do with residual classes and prime numbers?

And also when I would do the non-deterministic automaton, I would only need 9 states. Can this be true? 

Thank you very much again!!

Comment: Bonus question: if you're asked a similar question but with 4 and 6 instead of 3 and 5, how many states would you need?

Comment: The answer to the Bonus question would be 6, right?

Comment: really? Try it. I don't think it can be done with just 6 states (although proving that something is impossible is much harder than proving that something is possible)

Comment: Why not? 

q0 --> q1
q1 --> q2
q2 --> q3 
q4 --> q5 
q5 --> q0

q0, q2 and q4 are my final states. 
These are always multiples of 2 and 6.

Comment: I said 4 and 6, not 2 and 6. Yes you are correct, if it had been 2 and 6, then 6 states would be enough. In fact 2 states would have been enough!!

Comment: Oh sorry, thats awkward. Then 24 states? 
Oh yes you are right. 2 states are also enough, thanks.

Comment: 24 states work for 4 and 6 yes, but actually you can do it in 12 states. Because gcd(6, 4) = 12. So if you handle the 12 remainders modulo 12, then you're sure to handle correctly all numbers modulo 4 and modulo 6.

Comment: This thing with gcd is specific to this arithmetic problem; in general if you have a language K recognised by an automaton A and a language L recognised by an automaton B, then you can build an automaton C to recognise language (K union L) by having states (a, b) for every state a of A and every state b of B.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to validate both multiples of *n* and *m*, start by just writing out every possible state until things repeat, which would be *n x m* states. So for *n*=3 and *m*=5:

```
S
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Then you mark terminals:

```
 S
 1
 2
(3)
 4
(5)
(6)
 7
 8
(9)
(10)
 11
(12)
 13
 14
(15)
```

And then you optimize by removing irrelevant nodes. For example, we don't need to visit 7, and then 8, just to get to 9, we can remove 8 and instead make the path from the non-terminal 7 to the terminal (9) consume two tokens. If we don't have that many tokens to consume, the DFA halts in a non-terminal state.